# Google map layout called from button press crash

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to implement `Google Maps API` in an Android application. This works just fine when the google map is in an app alone But when I try to open the layout containing the map via a button tap from another layout, it crashes at the line: setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps); in the mapsactivity.java.

here is the function used to call the map layout:

```
public void runSSH(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The mapsactivity.java was auto generated by AndroidStudio, but I will still put it here:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

And here is the Activitymaps.xml (auto-generated as well):

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hosenbocus.azhar.droner.MapsActivity" />
```

I did add the API key in the manifest and in the google_maps_api.xml

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MYKEY-AIzaSyCf0-a3jUzVrL4PJwCo1q6W60YTxu-U7F0" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />




<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
    AIzaSyCf0-a3jUzVrL4PJwCo1q6W60YTxu-U7F0
</string>
```

Here is the trace log:

```
    03-10 14:47:20.937 22341-22341/com.hosenbocus.azhar.droner E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hosenbocus.azhar.droner/com.hosenbocus.azhar.droner.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
    at com.hosenbocus.azhar.droner.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:20)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The API key can only be specified once. It is recommended that you use the meta-data tag with the name: com.google.android.geo.API_KEY in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
    at maps.db.r.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.cz.c.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.d$a.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:62)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:347)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ah.b(:com.google.android.gms:179)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(:com.google.android.gms:100)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ag.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:62)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:347)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zzs(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzzW(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1142)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2287)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895) 
    at com.hosenbocus.azhar.droner.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:20) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me, I'm stuck on this for 2 days already now. I'm a beginner to android development, there might be something obvious that I missed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: whats your line 20 in mapsactivity ?

Comment: line 20 is:

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is :

```
The API key can only be specified once. It is recommended that you use the meta-data tag with the name: com.google.android.geo.API_KEY in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

**Instant of**

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MYKEY-AIzaSyCf0-a3jUzVrL4PJwCo1q6W60YTxu-U7F0" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

**use only**

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```